# How to Display Existing User Pictures In Codeigniter.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

I have a complete php script which i bought from codecanyon and the Author does not support costum work... it was made with Codeigniter framework and its working fine and perfectly but the script does not support

1. Ability for User to Upload Profile Image
2. Ability for uploaded image be shown in profile page. 
   3 Ability to ReUpload and or delete image.....

I have search google for it and could not find answers to this.

I have tried Creating >Upload-Controller > Upload View > Upload
Model, which only upload to a specified folder in a specific url e.g site.com/uploadimage.

I want to ask if there is any way to integrate this feature to the system... Am a php newbie.
Many Thank in Advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question asks to "GIMMY THE CODEZ", but that doesn't work here 

and will get your question **down-voted** then put **on-hold** and eventually **closed**. You 

need to write your own code and once you run into a specific problem then use Stack Overflow to 

ask for help for that specific problem. As your question is written now it is way to broad. 

Please read 
[**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site
[**Taking the Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: but i have the right to modify its source code as Licence given by the script Author.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this is **not** a code writing service. post what you have tried, and what errors have occured along the way, and *maybe* we can help you. otherwise if you have no knowledge of CI either start with some tuts or hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.
Create this folder path for uploading the image : **app_data/images/account/**

```
// Your Controller
Class User extends CI_Controller
{
    // This upload method
    function upload_user_photo()
    {
        $path  = 'app_data/images/account/';
        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $file_name                  = increment_string('image_profile', '-'); //use codeigniter string helper
        $config['upload_path']      = $path;
        $config['file_name']        = $file_name;
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = '100';
        $config['max_width']        = '1024';
        $config['max_height']       = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

        //Take an action if photo has been uploaded
        if($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

            // View response from upload data
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($upload_data);
            echo "</pre>";

            // Array key is column name of your table
            $data = 
            [
                'user_id' => 'insert our user id',
                'photo' => $upload_data['file_name']
            ];

            //Take action save to your model
            $this->load->model('your_model_name');

            $this->your_model_name->save_profile_image($data);
        }
    }
}


#Model
Class Your_model_name extends CI_Model
{
    function save_profile_image($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Read more about [codeigniter upload setting preferences](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences)